# Funtoo: define for emerge to use certain version in futher world update

Tags: gentoo, emerge, funtoo

Funtoo has no libxklavier-5.4 that is required by latest xfc4-xkb-plugin-0.8.1

```
# emerge xfce4-xkb-plugin
Calculating dependencies... done!

emerge: there are no ebuilds to satisfy ">=x11-libs/libxklavier-5.4:=".
(dependency required by "xfce-extra/xfce4-xkb-plugin-0.8.1::desktop-kit" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "xfce4-xkb-plugin" [argument])
```

I installed other version:

```
# emerge "=xfce-extra/xfce4-xkb-plugin-0.7.1-r1"
```

I need to say Funtoo not to use latest xfce4-xkb-plugin while emerge will update world. How to do this?

Comment: yes, but 0.7.1-r1 that is working

Comment: 0.8.1 is not working cause needs libxklavier-5.4. But 0.7.1-r1 works ok. my config is this: >xfce-extra/xfce4-xkb-plugin-0.7.1-r1 . it masks all new versions and says Funtoo to use only 0.7.1-r1 version